# Why the below mentioned code is not able to differentiate between the <hr3> heading and normal text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my very first webpage using HTML. I am using the following code:

```
<h3>Education: </hr3>
    <ul>
        <li> Bachelor's of Engineering in Electrical Engineering.</li>
        <li> Completed 12th standard. </li>
        <li> Completed 10th standard. </li>
    </ul>
```

But this code is not able to differentiate between the heading "Education" and the unordered list.

The complete text is coming under  heading only.

```
<h3>Education: </hr3>
    <ul>
        <li> Bachelor's of Engineering in Electrical Engineering.</li>
        <li> Completed 12th standard. </li>
        <li> Completed 10th standard. </li>
    </ul>
```

Education should be in h3 heading and the unordered list should be in plain text.

Comment: You closing header tag should be h3, not hr3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing tag for the header needs to match the opening tag for the header -- otherwise it won't stop the effect of the opening tag.  In short:

```
<h3>Education: </hr3>
```

Should be

```
<h3>Education: </h3>
```